# Scss change color of mat-checkbox if disabled

Tags: angular, sass

In my scss file for my component I have this to set the background color for mat-checkbox when checked:

```
/deep/.mat-checkbox-checked.mat-accent .mat-checkbox-background, .mat-checkbox-indeterminate.mat-accent .mat-checkbox-background {
    background-color: #A5C73C;
}
```

Now I need to set a different color for checkboxes when they are selected but disabled (some data have to be always selected and their checkbox disabled to prevent unchecking). How do I specify the disabled property with /deep/ in scss?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
/deep/.mat-checkbox-checked.mat-accent.mat-checkbox-disabled .mat-checkbox-background, .mat-checkbox-indeterminate.mat-accent .mat-checkbox-background {
    background-color: (your color);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

[Usr's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56901300/3291390) put me on the right track but `/deep/` would not work for me so I had to change it to use the `::ng-deep` pseudo class. Note that according to [the documentation](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles), this will make the style global. Also, in my case, I had to use `!important` to get the style to take effect.

```
::ng-deep.mat-checkbox-checked.mat-accent.mat-checkbox-disabled .mat-checkbox-background, .mat-checkbox-indeterminate.mat-accent .mat-checkbox-background {
  background-color: #ccc !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That works for me:

```
<mat-checkbox class="my_checkbox" [disabled]="true" [checked]="true"></mat-checkbox>

<mat-checkbox class="my_checkbox" [disabled]="true" [checked]="false"></mat-checkbox>
```

And scss for unchecked and checked:

```
my_checkbox {
  :not(.mat-checkbox-checked) {
    .mat-checkbox-frame {
      // Your style
    }
  }
  
  &.mat-checkbox-checked {
    .mat-checkbox-frame {
      // Your style
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
::ng-deep .mat-checkbox-checked.mat-accent.mat-checkbox-disabled .mat-checkbox-background, .mat-checkbox-indeterminate.mat-accent .mat-checkbox-background {
  background-color:#d9d9d9 !important;
}
```

Comment: for enabled checkbox:

Comment: ::ng-deep .mat-checkbox-checked.mat-accent .mat-checkbox-background,
.mat-checkbox-indeterminate.mat-accent .mat-checkbox-background {
  background-color: #d13730 !important;
  border-radius: 0.25em;
}