# Scss change color of mat-checkbox if enabled

Tags: css, angular, checkbox, angular-material

is there a way to change the color of mat-checkboxes if they're checked and enabled. I've tried something similiar to this question [Scss change color of mat-checkbox if disabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56901233/scss-change-color-of-mat-checkbox-if-disabled) and used enabled instead of disabled but it isn't working.

This is my css code for the checkboxes:

```
:host ::ng-deep .mat-checkbox-checked.mat-accent.mat-checkbox-enabled .mat-checkbox-background {
  background-color: red !important;
}
```

If I swap enabled with disabled it works fine, but it's not what I want. My goal is that only checkboxes which are enabled and checked are given a ceratin color of background and tick.

Answer (score 0):

youll need to add these classes to have the required colors you want ,I tested them on stackblitz for angular  ,first one is for ripple color ,second one for checked background color and the third class is for icons color.

```css
::ng-deep .mat-checkbox-ripple .mat-ripple-element {
  background-color: green !important;
}

::ng-deep .mat-checkbox-checked.mat-accent .mat-checkbox-background {
  background-color: red !important;
}

::ng-deep .mat-checkbox-checked.mat-accent .mat-checkbox-background svg path {
  stroke: blue !important;
}
/* ::ng-deep .mat-checkbox-checked.mat-accent .mat-checkbox-background {
  color: red !important;
} */
```

Comment: Thanks for this helpful answer. But for some reasons nothing is being displayed green. For what is ripple exactly?

Comment: that is for when you tap on the radio button and on tap when the ripple occurs you can change the color of the ripple as well though you didnt ask for them but i thought i should add it as well

Answer (score 0):

Since an enabled control does not has any class like .enabled... you could use :not() css selector to invert that:

```
:host ::ng-deep .mat-checkbox-checked.mat-accent:not(.mat-checkbox-disabled) .mat-checkbox-background {
  background-color: green !important;
}
```

[image: check box in 3 modes with that css considered]

Comment: Thanks, that did the job. Your and Skipper pk's answer really helped me.

Comment: Also you can follow angular theming docs to customize only checkbox colors in your component. https://material.angular.io/guide/theming